# SAS - Find value in a column and display that value in excel export

Tags: sas

I am trying to basically do this :

I have a frequency query running on a data set which will output the result in excel.

I also want to add a column to the output in which the value will be based on what is listed in a particular cell or a particular column.

How would I go about this? (*very new sas user)

Comment: Can you give an example or say a bit more about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without hearing more information, I assume what you're trying to do is save the output of your proc freq and then manipulate it further with a data step.

Simple example of this:

```
data beer;
  length firstname favbrand $20.;
  input firstname $
        favbrand  $;
  datalines;
John bud
Steve dogfishhead
Jason coors
Anna anchorsteam
Bob bud
Dan bud
;
run;

proc freq data=beer;
  table favbrand / out=freqout;
run;

data beerstat(keep=favbrand status);
  set freqout;
  * create a new column called "status" based on the count column ;
  if (count >=2) then status="popular";
  else status = "hipster";
run;

* instead of proc print you can send your output to excel with proc export ;
proc print data=beerstat;
run;
```